# .on() in jQuery not working for delegated events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to figure out the relatively new (at least for me, I guess) `.on()` method provided with jQuery versions 1.7.x onwards. We've been using `live(), bind()` in our code to handle event handlers till now and we're thinking of an overhaul because of the [performance issues](http://paulirish.com/2010/on-jquery-live/) which `.live()` seems to have.
So here's my problem. This is the page structure I have in my page:

```
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="default"></div>
        <div class="close">Close</div>
        <div id="extras">//some random stuff// </div> 
    </div>
```

I've created an object to store frequently used selectors to such as `$(document), $("#header"), $("#footer")` like this:

```
   var elements = {
        $doc: $(document),
        $foo: $("#footer"),
        $head: $("#header")
   };
```

The behavior expected from the click of `.close` inside `#footer` is that `#extras` must hide from view. I tried to bind the click event of `.close` to `#footer` (*delegated*) like this:

```
elements.$foo.on("click","div.close",hideFooter)
```

**WHICH DID NOT WORK**. But, if bound to `elements.$doc` like this:

```
elements.$doc.on("click", "div.close", hideFooter);
```

**IT WORKS**. But isn't this how `.live()` works? (If for every click it should to go to the DOM start and bubble down to `div.close`)

Am I doing something wrong here?

**EXTRA INFO**
The contents of the anonymous function `hideFooter` are :

```
    function hideFooter(event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).next().hide("slow")
                              .closest("#footer").css({ "opacity": "0.8" });
        $("#default").show();
    }
```

**THE CODE SEQUENCE in default.js**

```
    var elements = {
            $doc: $(document),
            $foo: $("#footer"),
            $head: $("#header")
       };

  elements.$doc
       .ready(function () {
         elements.$foo.on(events.click, "div.close", hideFooter);
       })
      .on(events.click, "#content", HideHeaderFooter)
      .on(events.hover, "#footer", showFooter);
```

Comment: Does the footer element exist when you do the dom selection? `$foo: $("#footer"),` If not, you need to delay the selection until the element has loaded.

Comment: Well, you're doing it correctly as long as the `#footer` elements has loaded before the code runs. Need to see more code to know what's going on.

Comment: please show the context of var elements = {
        $doc: $(document),...

Comment: Its all static html. And this is all I have as of now :) I havent typed anymore than this.

Comment: @JQliker: We're seeing fragments of what you have, but we don't know how it's all put together. Where is the script located? What measures did you take to ensure the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Edited the question to include code sequence.

Comment: I see your update, but you're still not telling us where your script is in relation to the DOM, and what measures you're taking to ensure the DOM is loaded. For example, if that script is at the top of the page, you can put your code in a jQuery `.ready()` handler to make sure its execution is delayed until the DOM has loaded. `$(function() { /* your code here */ });` ...Or you could just put the script toward the bottom of the page, usually just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @user1689607 Should the event handler be placed inside DOM ready? I've used till now and it worked like magic even if used outside DOM ready..so I'm a novice to this :)

Comment: @JQliker: The DOM selection and therefore the binding of the handler should be either at the bottom of the page, or in the ready handler. The reason is that `document` is always available, but elements like `body` and its descendants are only available after that part of the page has loaded. I'm typing up an answer right now.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/cuU39/

Comment: @user1689607 Ive put the updated code in the question with the footer event in DOM ready event. Still didnt work.

Comment: @JQliker: Again, the DOM selection needs to be in the ready handler. You can't select an element that doesn't yet exist. If your code runs at the top of the page, and your code does this `$("#footer")`, that means it's searching for an element with that ID. But because your code is at the top, it runs before the rest of the page is loaded so the element doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure the `footer` element is loaded before your script runs, you can put your script toward the bottom of the page.

```
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="default"></div>
        <div class="close">Close</div>
        <div id="extras">//some random stuff// </div> 
    </div>

    <script src="/default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

---

Or if you want your `<script>` to be in the `<head>` of the page, you can wrap your code in a jQuery `.ready()` handler so that it doesn't run until the page is loaded.

```
$(function() {
       // Code in here will not run until the rest of the page has loaded.
    var elements = {
            $doc: $(document),
            $foo: $("#footer"),
            $head: $("#header")
       };

    elements.$doc
      .on(events.click, "#content", HideHeaderFooter)
      .on(events.hover, "#footer", showFooter);
    elements.$foo.on("click","div.close",hideFooter);
});
```

So now your code will be delayed until the page has loaded, and so your `footer` element will exist and be ready for DOM selection.

Comment: +1 This has to be the reason - In my fiddle if I do a no wrap(head) it will not work.. but onDomReady works fine

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put it together in the handler? This *should* work:

```
elements.$foo.on("click","div.close", function() {
     $(this).next().hide("slow").closest("#footer").css({ "opacity": "0.8" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this

```
elements.$foo.on("click","div.close",HideFooter)
```

Did you mean this?

```
elements.$foo.on("click","div.close",hideFooter)
```

Notice the 'H' in your function name.

Comment: It was typo when i typed it here :) changed :)